# Loop in order to create several DataFrames for each sheet in an Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file with 36 sheets. I would like to iterate over each sheet of the Excel file and create a DataFrame for each sheet in the file. 
Also, I would like the DataFrames to be named with the name of the sheet. 
I am a newbie in python and in this site, I saw that there is a similar topic for this question but it doesn't answer completely to my question.

This is the for loop I wrote so far, but it is not doing what I have in my mind.
With the last record of this code, I am obtaining a dataframe called sheet1 with the last data inside the last sheet in the excel file.
What I would like to obtain is to have 36 different dataframe for each sheet in the excel, and if possible each dataframe has to be named with the name of each spreadsheet (I think that the dictionary called "dict_of_sheet" contain all the 36 table that I want to upload in python from excel.

Would you help me to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

```
multi_sheet_file = pd.ExcelFile("pathfile_Name")
excel_sheet_names = multi_sheet_file.sheet_names

dict_of_sheets = {}
for sheet in excel_sheet_names:
    dict_of_sheets[sheet] = pd.read_excel(multi_sheet_file, sheet_name=sheet)

sheet1=dict_of_sheets[sheet]
```

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(your_file,sheet_name=None)` reads the dataframe as an ordered dict with the key as the sheet name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `exec()` for this. `exec()` function is used for the dynamic execution of Python program which can either be a string or object code.

You can use xlrd library to get the sheet names too. You can use pandas libary too for the sheet names(I didn't look around, there definitely might be a way of doing that).

```
import xlrd

filename='try.xlsx'
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, on_demand=True)
sheet_names=xls.sheet_names()

print(sheet_names)
```

Output:

```
['see1', 'see2', 'Sheet3']
```

Now that you've got sheet names, you can now run loop over them and use exec to create dataframes of same name:

```
for name in sheet_names:
    exec(f"{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")
```

This creates dataframes with filenames as the see1, see2 and Sheet3.

```
print(see1)
```

Output:

```
   Col1  COl2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4
3     4     4
```

Hope this is what you need.

> **NOTE**: In case your sheet name is just numbers, then it won't be possible to name a variable as just a number, so you might have to assign it a new name.

So just for the OP's case, here's a solution:

```
for name in sheet_names:
    if name.isdigit():
        exec(f"Sheet_name{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")

    else:
        exec(f"{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")
```

So what this code will do is, if you have any sheet name which is just numeric, it will create the variable name as, Sheet_name{the numeric}.

So in my case, I had sheet names as: `['Sheet1', '245', 'Sheet3']` and I finally get the second variable as a dataframe as below:

```
print(Sheet_name245)
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```

Hope this helps with your case.

> **NOTE2:** The case where the sheet name has a decimal in it and not just integer as a number, then the above code will stop, since a
>   decimal can't be used in a variable name either. So here's a
>   workaround:

```
for name in sheet_names:
    if name.isdigit():
        exec(f"Sheet_name{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")

    elif '.' in name:
        temp_name=name.replace('.', '_')
        exec(f"Sheet_name{temp_name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")        

    else:
        exec(f"{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")
```

So now we will get filename for `245.63` as `Sheet_name245_63`. I hope now your issue is resolved.

Comment: Error for loop `for name in sheet_names: If I run the following loop, I`ll obtain this error
    exec(f"{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")`  SyntaxError: can't assign to literal (<string>, line 1) Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\\anaconda3\lib\sitepackages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-258-eb451fb35c61>", line 2, in <module> exec(f"{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')") File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Comment: Which Python version are you using, what Operating System are you using? Can you give me that update?

Comment: One more issue that I can think of is, that your sheet name itself is a number.

So, in Python, you can't do 1=14, 1 is not recognised as a variable name, or even a string is not recognised as a variable name. I mean you can't have, 'sheet1'=45, it can just be a simple variable name, sheet1=45. That's just a guess. Can you check what are you getting as your sheet names and what is their type? Are they coming as strings or just integers by any chance?

Comment: I've added a solution to your problem in the original answer, you can use that, it should surely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank a lot for your support @AmitAmola. Yes the names of the sheets are numbers. So I Found the problem that you've mentioned. Anyhow, the loop stopped at the fourth sheet of the excel, because the fifth (and the others) has a point inside the name. The name of the consequent sheets are 4.5 ; 4.7 etc.. I tried to modify your code above, in order to consider this case but it didn't work. `if name.isdigit() or isinstance(name,float):
        exec(f"Sheet_name{name}=pd.read_excel('{filename}', sheet_name='{name}')")`

Comment: See, that again would be an issue. You can't name a variable as just an integer, so doing something like Sheet{the number}, example, Sheet45 instead of just 45 is fine. But again, you can't have '.' in the variable name. You should checkout the naming convention in Python. Anyway for your case, I'll add a small solution which should work just for your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AmitAmola. Now the loop is perfectly working. I just add another else if because I found another issue in the name of a sheet in Excel. This sheet has a spaces in the name ("18 "), so the loop stopped in this point. `  elif '.' in name:
        temp_name=name.replace(' ', '_') ` Otherwise, I think that work also this statement `elif '.' in name:
        temp_name=name.replace('.', '_').replace(' ', '_')

Comment: Haha, you keep on getting more and more issues. Well you can just strip the string and remove any spaces from either side of the sheet name. In fact you can do a .replace(' ', '') too. I hope now you won't get any more errors.