# Read each excel sheet as a different dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have an excel file with 40 sheet_names. I want to read each sheet to a different dataframe, so I can export an xlsx file for each sheet.
Instead of writing all the sheet names one by one, I want to create a loop that will get all sheet names and add them as a variable in the "sheet_name" option of "pandas_read_excel"

I am trying to avoid this:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\filename.xlsx', sheet_name= 'Sheet1');
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\filename.xlsx', sheet_name= 'Sheet2');
....
df40 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\filename.xlsx', sheet_name= 'Sheet40');
```

thank you all guys

Comment: Just use `dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name=None)` to create a dictionary of sheet_name->dataframe ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop in order to create several DataFrames for each sheet in an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431442/loop-in-order-to-create-several-dataframes-for-each-sheet-in-an-excel-file)

Comment: see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying `sheet_name` as `None` with [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) reads all worksheets and returns a `dict` of `DataFrames`.

```py
import pandas as pd

file = 'C:\Users\filename.xlsx'
xl = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
sheets = xl.keys()

for sheet in sheets:
    xl[sheet].to_excel(f"{sheet}.xlsx")
```

Comment: In general should the of `exec` be avoided. There are often clearer, more direct ways to get the same effect. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the resource, I missed the export part in the question anyway.

Comment: I modified the export path and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=None)
for sheet in xlsx.keys(): xlsx[sheet].to_excel(sheet+'.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```